# pynput doesn't recognise a key on numpad

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pynput, numpad

I have a RaspberryPi running Raspbian 3.12. I need to control the device with a just a few keys and the easiest approach seems to be to use just a numpad.  I use the pynput keyboard library to detect key presses in the background; it works a treat.

I can detect all keys in a little python script using pynput -- except that the decimal point key isn’t detected when numlock is on (it works with numlock off) and that the key labelled 5 isn’t detected at all (numlock on or off). Both keys work as expected in other applications such as an editor.

Has anyone an idea on whay to do? Is there a way to find the key codes or is there anything else anyine can suggest?

Thanks,
Niels

Comment: Did you try a different keypad?

Comment: Thanks, Tom; I only have a "normal" keyboard (without a numbed) -- and all keys are detected there -- so: no.

Comment: How are you detecting the keys? If you put a breakpoint when any key is pressed, does the `5` key hit the breakpoint?